# Sync Realtime DB with Authentication users list

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm creating all users from Firebase console, Now I wanted copy all users to realtime db under `users` node.

Below is my Google cloud function

```
exports.getAllUsers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    app.auth().listUsers(1000)
      .then((listUsersResult) => {
        var db = admin.database();
        var ref = db.ref("users");
        const usersRef = ref.child('users');
        usersRef.set(listUsersResult,  { merge: true } );

        ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
          console.log(snapshot.val());
        });


        // admin.database().ref('users').set(listUsersResult, { merge: true })
        res.send(listUsersResult);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Oh no! Firebase listUsers Error:', error);
      });
  });
});
```

By using `firebase-admin`, I could get all the users list but When I tried to update the DB i'm getting the below error

> Oh no! Firebase listUsers Error: Error: Reference.set failed: onComplete argument must be a valid function.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The `set()` and `once()` methods are asynchronous. You need to use `then()` or async/await to get the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `{ merge: true }` to the call to `set`, but that option only exists in the Firestore API - not in the API of the Realtime Database. So:

```
usersRef.set(listUsersResult);
```

In addition, you need to handle the asynchronous nature of `set` and `once` as Renaud commented. So combining the above with that gets to:

```
usersRef.set(listUsersResult)
.then(() => {
  ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    res.send(listUsersResult);
  });
});
```

That leaves the fact that your `usersRef` refers to `/users/users` in the database, which you'll probably also want to fix.